# How to catch row(s) deleted in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, events, vba

I would like to get the row numbers of each deleted row after or before the rows are deleted in VBA.

There is an Event BeforeDelete() but when I delete a row it is not triggered?

Is there any other events or ways I could do this?

Here's kinda what I want:

`Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDelete()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub`

Comment: Please display the code you have tried thusfar.  StackOverflow is a collaborative site which helps with specific coding issues, not a code-for-you service.  To give some guidance, when you loop in reverse order of the rows to delete, before deleting row i (variable), you would MsgBox i so it displays.

Answer (score 3):

The following event macro will tell you whenever an entire row is deleted or inserted:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox Target.Row
    End If
End Sub
```