# VBA Macro - Row Data Not Preserved When Previous Row Is Deleted

Tags: excel

DESIRED BEHAVIOR - Retain data entered by User

SPECIFIC PROBLEM - The macro deletes data from a subsequent row when one row is deleted.

I have a macro that looks at the dropdown entry in Column F and populates the rest of the row with cells that are either locked and say 'NR' or are unlocked and colored blue - the User then can enter data into the blue boxes and after entry the cells turn green.  All works fine, but if the User deletes a row (which the client wants the User to be able to do), the row that is moved up now lacks the User's entries because the macro is running again, sees the updated dropdown entry in the box and runs the NR/blue script again.  How can I retain the entry data upon deletion of the row above it?

In the first picture we see that Row 6 (Emergency Generators) has a '3' in J6.  Then we delete Row 5 (Transformer), making what was Row 6 now Row 5.  But in the second picture (the 'after') Row 5 (Emergency Generators) is missing the '3' that should be in J5 because the macro picks up like F5 is 'chosen' and the NR/blue script runs, creating a fresh row.  Note that it doesn't remove the '7' from the last row (we don't want it to be removed so that's good) because it doesn't sense a new choice being made. Thoughts?

[image]

[image]

PARTIAL MACRO

```
'Array with all the possible scenarios: _
-row 1 is for unlocked cells, row 2 for locked cells, row 3 for cleared cells _
-column 1 is for the cell value, column 2 is for the actual range, column 3 is for the interior color _
-set cell value as Empty returns an empty cell _
-set interior color as Empty return a cell with no color

VarScenarios(1, 1) = Empty
Set VarScenarios(1, 2) = RngUnlock
VarScenarios(1, 3) = RGB(155, 194, 230)
    
VarScenarios(2, 1) = "NR"
Set VarScenarios(2, 2) = RngLock
VarScenarios(2, 3) = RGB(128, 128, 128)

VarScenarios(3, 1) = Empty
Set VarScenarios(3, 2) = RngClear
VarScenarios(3, 3) = RGB(128, 128, 128)
```

Comment: I would suggest that instead of an multi-dimensional array, use a `Collection` of one-dimensional arrays. Each entry in your `Collection` would match a row, with the array holding the values you need to fill/format. If you `.Remove` the fifth `Collection` entry, then the (previously) sixth entry now becomes the fifth entry.

Comment: @PeterT thanks for the suggestion.  Can you tell me how you might implement something like that?  When the User deletes a row it triggers the macro to run - I'm not grasping how a collection would solve that.  I thought a viable solution would be to embed some code in the macro stopping it from running upon a row delete, but not sure how to code that.

Comment: How does the user delete a row - selecting a row, then right-click/delete? If this is the case, then won't the other rows (below and above) retain their values? I'm unclear what the macro is doing and how it is triggered.

Comment: @PeterT yes they delete a row by selecting a row then right-click/delete?  The rows above and below (except for the immediate row below) DO retain their values (see images in post).  But the act of deleting a row (and hence moving up the previous row) acts as if Column F has been 'clicked' and therefore runs the macro, which newly locks and unlocks fresh cells and clears the existing data.  This is why only the row below the deleted row is affected.

Comment: I assume that you're catching changes to the sheet with the `Worksheet_Change` event. In the event handler, you can detect if the sheet change is only deleting a row with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49560539/4717755). So if the user DOES delete a row, then don't run your macro. If the user DOES NOT delete a row and changes something else, then your macro should run.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT.  This is the suggested script in the answer you provided...       
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = Columns.Count Then MsgBox Target.Row    End If  End Sub....it would appear I would need more than that. I think that this only accounts for selecting an entire row and not the actual delete or am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255733/discussion-between-petert-and-gregg-rosenstein).